# GLM residual assumptions modelling binary response variable

Tags: generalized-linear-model, binary-data, assumptions

I'm taking a intro to modelling course at my university. We are currently learning about modelling Binary response data.

I am confused about the assumptions of the Generalised Linear Model, in R.

Would this residual plot indicate violation of any assumptions?

Here incidence is 1 or 0, area and distance are numeric continuous.

TIA

[image]